# How can I fix the hover and transition on my nav menu?

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover, css-transitions

I'm building a vertical tabbed navigation menu.

I'm having two problems when I hover over the tabs.

First, only the tab that is hovered is supposed to expand. But what actually happens is multiple tabs expand.

Second, the expand transition is not smooth. It's very jerky and annoying.

I've gone through my code but can't figure it out. What am I missing?

Each tab should expand smoothly and by itself when hovered.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Live site: http://gearbags.com/store/shop/

HTML:

```
<!-- First Tab --> 

<div id="slideout">

    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Y4LMQhS.png" alt="tab" />


    <div id="slideout_inner">

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/">ACCESSORIES</a></h4><br />
      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxfb30-accessories/">LXFB30</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxfgc-hd-accessories/">LXGC-HD</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxfgs-accessories/">LXFGS</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxfgs-hd/">LXFGS-HD</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-a/">LXMK-A</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-b/">LXMK-B</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-c/">LXMK-C</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-d/">LXMK-D</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-e/">LXMK-E</a></h4>

    </div>
  </div>

<!-- Second Tab --> 

<div id="slideout-fire">

    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Y4LMQhS.png" alt="tab" />



    <div id="slideout_inner_fire">

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/">FIREFIGHTER</a></h4><br />
      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxfb30-accessories/">LXFB30</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxfgc-hd-accessories/">LXGC-HD</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxfgs-accessories/">LXFGS</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxfgs-hd/">LXFGS-HD</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-a/">LXMK-A</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-b/">LXMK-B</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-c/">LXMK-C</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-d/">LXMK-D</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-e/">LXMK-E</a></h4>

    </div>
  </div>


<!-- Third Tab --> 


<div id="slideout-medical">

    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Y4LMQhS.png" alt="tab" />



    <div id="slideout_inner_medical">

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/">MEDICAL</a></h4><br />

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-a/">LXMB5-HP</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxfb30-accessories/">LXMB15</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxfgc-hd-accessories/">LXMB20</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxfgs-accessories/">LXMB30</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxfgs-hd/">LXMB35</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-a/">LXMB40</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-b/">LXMB50</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-c/">LXMB65</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-a/">LXMK-A</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-b/">LXMK-B</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-c/">LXMK-C</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-d/">LXMK-D</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/lxsmk-e/">LXMK-E</a></h4>

    </div>
  </div>

<!-- Fourth Tab --> 


<div id="slideout-tactical">

    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Y4LMQhS.png" alt="tab" />



    <div id="slideout_inner_tactical">

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/accessories/">TACTICAL</a></h4><br />

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/tactical/lxpb10/">LXPB10</a></h4>

      <h4><a href="http://gearbags.com/store/product-category/tactical/lxpb40/">LXPB40</a></h4>


    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
/* ---------- First Tab ---------- */


#slideout {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: -500px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

#slideout img {
  position: relative;
    left: 75px;
  /* margin-left: -860px; */
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;


/*
position: relative;
  margin-left: -430px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  top: -58px;
  z-index: 0;*/
}

#slideout_inner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  /*left: -300px;*/
  left: -250px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#slideout_inner a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a5683;
}

#slideout:hover {
  /*left: 320px;*/
  /* left: 380px; */
    left: -155px;
}

#slideout:hover #slideout_inner {
  /*left: 35px;*/
  left: 125px;
}

.vertical-text {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.gbtitle {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a5683;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 1;
}

.gbtitle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a5683;

}

.gbtitle a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FF6824;
}

#slideout_inner a:hover {
  color: #FF6824;
}



/* ---------- Second Tab ---------- */


#slideout-fire {
  position: fixed;
  top: 220px;
  left: -500px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

#slideout-fire img {
  position: relative;
  /* margin-left: -860px; */
    left: 75px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;


/*
position: relative;
  margin-left: -430px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  top: -58px;
  z-index: 0;*/
}

#slideout_inner_fire {
  position: fixed;
  top: 250px;
  /*left: -300px;*/
  left: -250px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#slideout_inner_fire a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a5683;
}

#slideout-fire:hover {
  /*left: 320px;*/
  left: -115px;
}

#slideout-fire:hover #slideout_inner_fire {
  /*left: 35px;*/
  left: 125px;
}

.vertical-text {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.gbtitle {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a5683;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 1;
}

.gbtitle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a5683;

}

.gbtitle a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FF6824;
}

#slideout_inner_fire a:hover {
  color: #FF6824;
}



/* ---------- Third Tab ---------- */


#slideout-medical {
  position: fixed;
  top: 400px;
  left: -500px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

#slideout-medical img {
  position: relative;
  /* margin-left: -860px; */
    left: 75px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;


/*
position: relative;
  margin-left: -430px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  top: -58px;
  z-index: 0;*/
}

#slideout_inner_medical {
  position: fixed;
  top: 430px;
  /*left: -300px;*/
  left: -250px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#slideout_inner_medical a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a5683;
}

#slideout-medical:hover {
  /*left: 320px;*/
  left: -115px;
}

#slideout-medical:hover #slideout_inner_medical {
  /*left: 35px;*/
  left: 125px;
}

.vertical-text {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.gbtitle {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a5683;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 1;
}

.gbtitle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a5683;

}

.gbtitle a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FF6824;
}

#slideout_inner_medical a:hover {
  color: #FF6824;
}


/* ---------- Fourth Tab ---------- */


#slideout-tactical {
  position: fixed;
  top: 580px;
  left: -500px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

#slideout-tactical img {
  position: relative;
  /* margin-left: -860px; */
    left: 75px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;


/*
position: relative;
  margin-left: -430px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  top: -58px;
  z-index: 0;*/
}

#slideout_inner_tactical {
  position: fixed;
  top: 600px;
  /*left: -300px;*/
  left: -250px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#slideout_inner_tactical a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a5683;
}

#slideout-tactical:hover {
  /*left: 320px;*/
  left: -115px;
}

#slideout-tactical:hover #slideout_inner_tactical {
  /*left: 35px;*/
  left: 125px;
}

.vertical-text {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.gbtitle {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a5683;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 1;
}

.gbtitle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a5683;

}

.gbtitle a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FF6824;
}

#slideout_inner_tactical a:hover {
  color: #FF6824;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what's causing multiple tabs to expand when only one is hovered is the `width: 400px` declaration on all four `#slideout_inner-...` div children of the main tab container (`#slideout-...`).

This width is covering an area much greater than the tab it belongs to; it's overlapping other tabs. In testing in Chrome, if you just remove this width, the overlapping disappears and the width expands only enough to fill its content.

So, step one: remove `width: 400px` on all div children referenced above. This seems to fix the hover issue. The transitions are now smooth.  BUT the content is now gone from view.

To fix this, you need to adjust the positioning in the same four `slideout_inner-...` div children.

Try adding `margin-left: 175px` to each rule.

You may still need to tweak positioning a bit in order to align the text to your preferences. But I think the adjustments above solve both problems raised in your question.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/wf0658ko/1/

Comment: Thank you! This seems to correct the issue! I  changed margin left on each rule. As you mentioned I had to tweak it specifically for each item. The top two were 125px and the bottom two, 140px. One last thing to correct is the top one pushes the text out a little further upon hover. Going to work on that now! Thank you! I appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your `transition`; you are using the `transition-duration` property without setting an actual `transition`.
Add this shorthand property to your tabs and it should solve your problem:
`transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;`
The function on the side navigation is funky because your `transforms` maintain 450px of width and are covering the adjacent tabs.

Side note: if you aren't familiar with [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), it's a good place to find answers to your problems (like these).